# Adding a picture in javascript

Tags: javascript, image

Okay so I have a menu with names of transmissions. I'd like to add a small little transmission logo beside each tab. This is the code that I would like to add on to:

```
document.getElementById("nav02").innerHTML =
"<ul id='menu'>" +
(RIGHT HERE IS WHERE ID LIKE THE LOGO TO APPEAR, I AM NOT SURE IF THIS IS WHERE THE CODE WOULD GO EITHER)"<li><a href='32RH.html'>32RH</a></li>" +
"<li><a href='Build.html'>36RH</a></li>" +
"<li><a href='Customers.html'>42RH</a></li>" +
"<li><a href='About.html'>42RE</a></li>" +
"</ul>";
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use the list-style-image CSS property. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-image.asp

You can add this to your file somewhere in the head:

```
<style type="text/css">
    ul { list-style-image: url('images/transmission-logo'); }
</style>
```

If you want to do it right in the JavaScript:

```
    document.getElementById("menu").style.listStyleImage="url('images/transmission-logo')";
```

Comment: Thank you I see now, so I would use

ul {
    list-style-image: url('images/transmission-logo');
}

and put that where exactly? And how would I use that? Sorry this is my first day >.<

Comment: Whenever I add your code above the website blanks out. This is a javascript file by the way.

Comment: A style block like the one I created above should go in an HTML file. I'm assuming you have one of those because you have to link this JavaScript file from somewhere?

Comment: You do not put styles tag inside the JavaScript.

Comment: How could I do this more efficiently then if I may ask? I'm making my list in the javascript file (This is from a tutorial that I found and they were teaching how to add lists or whatever.)

Comment: Edited the answer again. I hope you include some kind of extension on your image file too. Doesn't it end in .jpg or .png or something?

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out, how do I use this?!

 document.getElementById("menu").style.listStyleImage="url('images/transmission-logo')";

Comment: Here's an example with a different pic: http://jsfiddle.net/thedouglenz/f7rL8j67/